# "Frightening" - participle?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech, participles

In this sentence, what part of speech is 'frightening':

"Halloween can also be **frightening** for pets."

Is it a participle? Or is it acting as a verb?

Comment: frightening is a adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frightening is an adjective. There is a natural process in which participles (which can be used as modifiers) become fixed as adjectives. It can be confusing when you try to parse a sentence. However if you check a dictionary you will find "frightening" listed as an adjective.

In a simpler example

> Dracula is a frightening monster (adjective)

> Dracula is frightening.  (probably an adjective)

But if there is a direct object, it must be a verb.

> Dracula is frightening the boys. (present continuous of verb "to frighten")